# Save list as list template from powershell

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-listtemplate

I can't find powershell command to save list instance as list template (to stp file) or export to stp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [SPList.SaveAsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.saveastemplate.aspx) via PowerShell should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

## Saving your list as Template

```
$site = get-spsite("<YourSite>")
$web = $site.RootWeb

$list = $web.Lists["<Your List>"]
$list.SaveAsTemplate(“Template Name”,”Template Title”,”Template Description”,1)
```

## 4th Parameter above -> if you want to save the specified site as template along with data use 1, otherwise use 0.

Creating a new list from the template created.

```
$listTemplates = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
$web.Lists.Add("<List Name>", "<List Desc>",$listTemplates["<Template List Name>"])
```